# Southwest corner of LAX has peculiar airplane parts, what is this area?

Tags: runways, firefighting, klax

In the Southwest corner of LAX (at the intersection of Imperial Highway and Pershing Dr.) there is a strange looking area that appears to have some abandoned airplane parts. Also, it looks like a road-striper had a good time one day doing donuts around one of the artifacts. Anyone familiar with this area and what it is used for?

[image]

See [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/33%C2%B055'55.9%22N+118%C2%B025'42.0%22W/@33.9322043,-118.4290073,366m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0)

Comment: Great answers - any insights on the yellow lines?

Comment: It looks like the lines are just practicing/testing for painting taxiway and runway markings.

Comment: From the question title I thought you meant the corner where Southwest's terminal is located. Upon looking at the map I learned that Southwest's terminal is actually located in the north east corner of the airport. I don't know why but that made me laugh.

Comment: Maybe to avoid disposing of unused paint they just dump it there. Or they were a little excited about the next NASCAR race and had their own.

Comment: Related: [LAFD Live Fire Training At LAX](http://www.flickriver.com/photos/lafd/sets/72157629048294587/)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

All major airports have practice fire fighting facilities equipped with dummy aircraft that are made of steel so they don't burn.

In addition to the dummy steel aircraft, they will often use retired aircraft to use for familiarization and evacuation training.

[image] 
[Source](http://news.hjnews.com/news/cache-valley-firefighters-practice-putting-out-aircraft-fires/article_11cb912c-d018-11df-920b-001cc4c002e0.html)
[image]
[Source](http://australianaviation.com.au/2013/04/new-fire-training-ground-for-melbourne-airport/)
[image]
[Source](http://www.airport-data.com/aircraft/photo/000936595.html)

Answer (score 39):

It is an aircraft fire simulator. They use it for training emergency response personnel and vehicles.

You can see them training on one in this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1bS6mb2FgEM)

[image]
Source: [Leipzig Halle Airport](https://www.leipzig-halle-airport.de/en/company/about-us/fire-training/aircraft-rescue-and-fire-fighting-976.html)

Comment: That confirms what I was going to post as a speculative comment. I got too busy playing around in the "3D" view and looking around the airport to come back to post...

Comment: Any idea what the "donut stripes" are in the OP's picture, though?

Comment: @yshavit I'm assuming like the other commentor on the OP that they test the stripe painting equipment and/or paint in that area.