# Strange plane-shaped object at UK airport

Tags: aircraft-identification

A friend sent me the following image, spotted at an UK airport. Do you have any idea what that might be?

It looks a bit like MD-11/DC-10 transport case, but i have no idea. Is something like this used to transport airplanes?

[image: Strange looking object at airport]

Comment: related, if not duplicate: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/26968/1467

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's a training rig for airport fire crews. They can usually be set on fire through whatever controlled means and the crews can practice approaching and working around aircraft.

In fact, after a cursory Google it's either the one at Heathrow or is near identical to it.

Comment: No need for being almost positive; that's what it is.

Comment: Maybe Heathrow has one as well, but it looks like the one at Stansted too - https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Stansted+Airport,+Stansted+CM24+1RW/@51.8873242,0.2326068,162m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x47d88e5e1bd094c3:0x1438d71a4733b651!8m2!3d51.8899385!4d0.2617407

Comment: More views of a fire simulator can be found on Heathrow's photo library: [fire simulator](http://photolibrary.heathrow.com/images/fire+simulator).

Answer (score 7):

That will be a fire trainer, for the airport fire fighters to practise procedures for different types of fire and smoke events. Here's the one at Amsterdam Airport:

[image][Image source](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=-TpzkEnqmDc)

Some of the fire trainers, if not most, have a replicated interior as well so that procedures can be trained for going into the plane, in realistic heat and smoke circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

This is a dummy aircraft used for training firefighters. I believe that it's coloured green so that random observers don't think that it's a true emergency.